# @RequiresRoles annotation not working in shiro

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, shiro

I am trying to explore on shiro framework. Authentication is working fine. I am facing an issue when authorizing. I am making use of shiro annotations @RequiresRoles for authorization. Eventhough I am using the annotation ,but it is not authorizing only for the role that I have specified. It is allowing all roles. Please find the code below that I have tried. I am using jersey and shiro.

Java Code:-

```
package com.somecompany.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.RequiresRoles;

@Path("/test")
public class HelloWorldService {

      @GET
      @Path("/{param}")
      @RequiresRoles(value= {"admin_role"})
      public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

            String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;
            System.out.println(SecurityUtils.getSubject().hasRole("admin_role"));

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

  }
```

}

Web.xml

```
   <servlet>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                         com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                    </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                 <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                 <param-value>com.somecompany.rest</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Pom.XML

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Included commons logging for shiro -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

shiro.ini

```
[users]
root = root,root_role
admin = admin,admin_role
test = test,test_role

[roles]
admin = *

[urls]
# The 'urls' section is used for url-based security
# in web applications.  We'll discuss this section in the
# Web documentation

/rest/** = authcBasic
```

Comment: I think Jersey has no way of recognizing this annotation you have to create a `DynamicFeature` ,  here is an example: https://gist.github.com/caseyscarborough/f4266646f727fa9f7cc6

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pom.xml lacks the following Shiro JAX-RS support lib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding this dependency to the project - `@RequiresRoles` has to work properly.